# update-manager stuck when trying to update to ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, update-manager, do-release-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and am at the point of preparing to upgrade, but it's stuck here.

[image: GUI status]

Running `do-release-upgrade` gets up to the line `Updating repository information`, where it also hangs.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

Updating repository information
```

I'm having no luck finding anyone with a similar problem, so I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. If you click on the terminal do you see any more info?  I would suggest `do-release-upgrade` from terminal as you get to see more information (clues) if there are issues.

Comment: running `do-release-upgrade` gets up to the line `Updating repository information` and is where it gets stuck from the terminal.

Comment: The output will be quite verbose, but you might want to try running `strace do-release-upgrade` and seeing what it's stuck on. `strace` is a command that prints out system calls like file operations, etc.

Comment: It's also possible your system is "stuck" doing some other package operation or that it has failed, in which case you might want to run `dpkg --configure -a` to reconfigure all your packages.

Comment: [This one](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6942#issuecomment-842629885) worked for me, going from 20.x in the MS store to 21.0. I had to Make it see non-LTS versions first: edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and set `Prompt=normal` (MS Store defaults it to `Prompt=lts`). I need a non-LTS because something I need is just plain busted with the current 20.x version, and people report it works in 21.

Answer (score 9):

I found that to get past "Updating repository information" I had to disable ipv6 (strace indicated that it was getting stuck trying to connect to an ipv6 address)

Comment: I had the same problem. Running the following commands before the upgrade solved the issue: `$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1`

Comment: This worked for me as well, thank you!

Comment: Had this problem upgrading to 22.04 from 20.04, this fixed it. IPv6 strikes again!

Comment: Same problem upgrading from 23.04 to 23.10. The two commands provided earlier in thread by @Karsten worked past it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there I've run into the same problem , running **do-release-upgrade** gets up to the line Updating repository information and is where it gets stuck from the terminal.

I've figured out that i'm running the command without sudo, after i used sudo it updated my Ubuntu, with no problems.